# Query optimization for multiple subsets

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sqlperformance, sql-optimization

I have a "personnel basic information table", and it will be referenced by many "personnel subset tables" (there is no relationship between these subset tables, they are just a subset of the basic information of the personnel).
Now there is a requirement to merge the "personnel subset" into a column based on the person's foreign key and display it as a field of the "personnel basic information" (after the "personnel subset" is merged, each person record will only display one row) .

And the basic personnel information and personnel subset information will be passed into the query conditions, so these conditions are dynamically assembled.

It has been implemented now, but the problem is that the query needs to be optimized. Execution will be particularly slow once.

Database is oracle 11g.

Here is the sql generated by a certain query:

```
WITH in_hr_work_party_current AS (
  SELECT 
    * 
  FROM 
    hr_work_party 
  WHERE 
    status = '1' 
    AND removaltime IS NULL 
    AND (
      appointorg IS NOT NULL 
      OR NAME IS NOT NULL
    )
), 
qv_hr_work_party_current AS (
  SELECT 
    empid, 
    listagg (
      DECODE (
        appointorg, NULL, '', 'oidstart' || appointorg || 'oidend-'
      ) || NVL (NAME, 'xx'), 
      ','
    ) WITHIN GROUP (
      ORDER BY 
        positiongrade ASC, 
        positionorder ASC, 
        appointtime ASC
    ) AS party_current_info 
  FROM 
    in_hr_work_party_current 
  GROUP BY 
    empid
), 
in_position_postwork_main AS (
  SELECT 
    po.empid, 
    working_coid_name AS post_main_coid_name, 
    working_poid_name AS post_main_poid_name, 
    officedepname AS post_main_officedepname, 
    post AS post_main_post, 
    posttype AS post_main_posttype, 
    workprof AS post_main_workprof, 
    starttime AS post_main_starttime, 
    FLOOR (
      CEIL (
        MONTHS_BETWEEN (
          NVL (
            TO_DATE (po.endtime, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 
            SYSDATE
          ), 
          TO_DATE (po.starttime, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
        )
      ) / 12
    ) || 'xx' AS post_main_years, 
    epo.entrytime AS post_main_entrytime, 
    ROW_NUMBER () OVER (
      PARTITION BY po.empid 
      ORDER BY 
        po.opttime DESC
    ) AS rn 
  FROM 
    hr_work_postworkinfo po, 
    hr_work_empposition epo, 
    v_waf_ac_organ_base dep 
  WHERE 
    DEP.OID = PO.officedepid 
    AND epo.wepid = po.wepid 
    AND po.status = '1' 
    AND po.officetype = '00' 
    AND is_date (po.starttime) = 1 
    AND (
      is_date (po.endtime) = 1 
      OR po.endtime IS NULL
    ) 
    AND epo.empsort = '01' 
    AND epo.subrelation = '01' 
    AND dep.orule LIKE '-xxxxx-%'
), 
qv_position_postwork_main AS (
  SELECT 
    * 
  FROM 
    in_position_postwork_main 
  WHERE 
    rn = 1
), 
in_postworkinfo AS (
  SELECT 
    po.*, 
    epo.entrytime, 
    epo.leavetime, 
    epo.empsort, 
    epo.empstatus, 
    epo.subrelation, 
    (
      working_coid_name || DECODE (
        working_poid_name, NULL, '', '-' || working_poid_name
      ) || DECODE (
        officedepname, NULL, '', '-' || officedepname
      )
    ) orgname, 
    FLOOR (
      CEIL (
        MONTHS_BETWEEN (
          NVL (
            TO_DATE (po.endtime, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 
            SYSDATE
          ), 
          TO_DATE (po.starttime, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
        )
      ) / 12
    ) postyear, 
    MOD (
      CEIL (
        MONTHS_BETWEEN (
          NVL (
            TO_DATE (po.endtime, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 
            SYSDATE
          ), 
          TO_DATE (po.starttime, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
        )
      ), 
      12
    ) postmonth, 
    ROW_NUMBER () OVER (
      PARTITION BY po.empid 
      ORDER BY 
        po.starttime DESC
    ) rn, 
    COUNT (*) OVER (PARTITION BY po.empid) ct 
  FROM 
    hr_work_postworkinfo po, 
    HR_WORK_EMPPOSITION EPO, 
    V_WAF_AC_ORGAN_BASE DEP 
  WHERE 
    po.wepid = EPO.wepid 
    AND PO.officedepid = DEP.OID 
    AND is_date (starttime) = 1 
    AND (
      is_date (endtime) = 1 
      OR endtime IS NULL
    ) 
    AND epo.empstatus != '05' 
    AND DEP.orule LIKE '-xxxxxx-%'
), 
qv_hr_position_postwork AS (
  SELECT 
    empid, 
    listagg (
      '[' || starttime || 'xx' || NVL (endtime, 'xx') || 'xx' || orgname || 'xx' || NVL (post, 'xx') || 'xx' || NVL (posttype, 'xx') || 'xx' || DECODE (
        postyear, 0, '', postyear || 'xx'
      ) || DECODE (
        postmonth, 0, '', postmonth || 'xxxx'
      ) || 'xx' || NVL (postgradation, 'xx') || 'xxxx' || entrytime || 'xx' || empsort || 'xx' || empstatus || 'xx' || subrelation || ']', 
      ','
    ) WITHIN GROUP (
      ORDER BY 
        starttime DESC
    ) || (
      CASE WHEN ct >= 5 THEN ',...' ELSE '' END
    ) work_info 
  FROM 
    in_postworkinfo 
  WHERE 
    rn <= 5 
  GROUP BY 
    empid, 
    ct
), 
in_hr_emp_basicinfo AS (
  SELECT 
    emp.* 
  FROM 
    hr_emp_basicinfo emp
), 
qv_hr_emp_basicinfo_view AS (
  SELECT 
    in_hr_emp_basicinfo.* 
  FROM 
    in_hr_emp_basicinfo
), 
in_party AS (
  SELECT 
    hr_work_party.NAME, 
    hr_work_party.empid, 
    hr_work_party.appointno, 
    hr_work_party.appointtime, 
    hr_work_party.removaltime, 
    hr_work_party.positiongrade, 
    NVL (
      waf_ac_organ.NAME, hr_work_party.appointorg
    ) apporg, 
    ROW_NUMBER () OVER (
      PARTITION BY hr_work_party.empid 
      ORDER BY 
        appointtime DESC, 
        removaltime DESC, 
        positiongrade ASC, 
        positionorder ASC
    ) rn, 
    COUNT (*) OVER (PARTITION BY hr_work_party.empid) ct 
  FROM 
    hr_work_party, 
    waf_ac_organ 
  WHERE 
    hr_work_party.status = '1' 
    AND hr_work_party.appointorg = waf_ac_organ.OID (+) 
    AND (
      hr_work_party.appointorg IS NOT NULL 
      OR hr_work_party.NAME IS NOT NULL
    )
), 
qv_hr_work_party AS (
  SELECT 
    empid, 
    listagg (
      '[' || appointtime || 'xx' || NVL (removaltime, 'xx') || ' ' || apporg || '-' || NVL (NAME, 'xx') || DECODE (
        NVL (appointno, 'xx'), 
        'xx', 
        '', 
        ' - ' || appointno
      ) || ']', 
      ','
    ) WITHIN GROUP (
      ORDER BY 
        rn ASC
    ) || (
      CASE WHEN ct > 10 THEN ',...' ELSE '' END
    ) app_party, 
    listagg (
      '[' || appointtime || 'xx' || NVL (removaltime, 'xx') || ' ' || apporg || '-' || NVL (NAME, 'xx') || DECODE (
        positiongrade, NULL, '', '(' || positiongrade || ')'
      ) || ']', 
      ','
    ) WITHIN GROUP (
      ORDER BY 
        rn ASC
    ) || (
      CASE WHEN ct > 10 THEN ',...' ELSE '' END
    ) AS party_grade 
  FROM 
    in_party 
  WHERE 
    rn <= 10 
  GROUP BY 
    empid, 
    ct
) 
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      dumb_table.*, 
      ROWNUM dumb_rn 
    FROM 
      (
        SELECT 
          qv_hr_work_party_current.party_current_info, 
          qv_position_postwork_main.post_main_coid_name, 
          qv_position_postwork_main.post_main_poid_name, 
          qv_position_postwork_main.post_main_officedepname, 
          qv_position_postwork_main.post_main_years, 
          qv_hr_emp_basicinfo_view.age, 
          qv_hr_emp_basicinfo_view.NAME, 
          qv_hr_position_postwork.work_info 
        FROM 
          qv_hr_work_party_current, 
          qv_position_postwork_main, 
          qv_hr_work_party, 
          qv_hr_position_postwork, 
          qv_hr_emp_basicinfo_view 
        WHERE 
          1 = 1 
          AND qv_hr_emp_basicinfo_view.empid = qv_hr_work_party_current.empid(+) 
          AND qv_hr_emp_basicinfo_view.empid = qv_position_postwork_main.empid(+) 
          AND qv_hr_emp_basicinfo_view.empid = qv_hr_work_party.empid (+) 
          AND qv_hr_emp_basicinfo_view.empid = qv_hr_position_postwork.empid 
          AND qv_hr_emp_basicinfo_view.empid IS NOT NULL 
        ORDER BY 
          qv_hr_emp_basicinfo_view.sno
      ) dumb_table
  ) 
WHERE 
  dumb_rn <= 30 
  AND dumb_rn > 0
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zq4dq.png)

Comment: First, can you edit your post to format your SQL statement so it is potentially readable.  Second, if you have an optimization problem, you're going to need to include a query plan.  Third, is this the simplest query that demonstrates the performance problem you're having?  If so, can you provide a reproducible test case?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help -- along with a clear explanation of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Has the implementation of the merged dataset been done creating a new table that holds the whole information, is it a view or is it part of the query you posted?
From the plan you posted, I think it's the last option, and in that case you're fully reading some tables and joining them with a hash (WAF_AC_ORGAN/WAF_AC_ORGAN2BIZ) and then doing a sort, that means you're missing indexes there. If because of the nature of the data you need to get, it's not possible to filter the tables in an initial phase, that query will need to manipulate a lot of data, and that takes also time.